# can i load local sdcard file in to web view in android

Tags: android

can i load local sdcard image file in to web view in android. If so how?
I want to display that image file from sdcard on web view. How do i do it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open Local Html File in Webview - Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812277/open-local-html-file-in-webview-android)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the sdcard path using -

```
  "file:///" +  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/";
```

and then use [Webview 's loadData](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadData%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

to load the image

Answer (score 0):

```
  Here images is the name of the folder containing images
```

String imagePath = this.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/images/";

```
     if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
     {
        Log.d("", "No SDCARD");
     } else {
         webView.loadUrl("file://"+imagePath+imageName);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String htmlContent = "<html><body><p><img src=\"file:///sdcard/image_name.jpg\" width=\"200\" height=\"133\" alt=\"\" /></p></body></html>";
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("not_needed", htmlContent, "text/html", "utf-8", "not_needed");
```