# Loading html file from local folder into webview

Tags: android, html, android-webview

I'm new to Android development.

I want to load *a html file* into *a webview*.

Note that there are so many relevant questions on SO like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812277/open-local-html-file-in-webview-android), but they all deal with getting **.html* from *assets* folder.

But I want to load html file from local folder, say "D://abc.html" because if my html is around 10Mb then corresponding apk size also goes upto 10mb.

Any help appreciated.

### EDIT

I tried `webView.loadUrl("file:///D:/Projects/myWebsite/index.html");`

but it gives `Web page not available` and `File not found error`.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use:

```
   WebView webView = // ...

   webView.loadUrl("file:///myPath/myFile.html");
```

In an Android application, files can be read from 3 types of locations:

- **Internal storage:** Each app has its own, file names are relative to this location. URL takes form `file:///myFolder/myFile.html`
- **External storage:** Needs permission and may not always be available. Get the root folder by calling [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()). So, construct the URL using: `String url = "file:///" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + "myFolder/myFile.html"`
- **Assets**: Stored in the apk. Read-only access. URL takes form `file:///android_asset/myFolder/myFile.html` (See also [Loading an Android Resource into a WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855008/loading-an-android-resource-into-a-webview))

Comment: `webView1.loadUrl("file:///C:/Users/myName/Desktop/e-magzine/index.html");` 

but it gives `Web page not available. File not found` message.

Comment: Android is a Linux implementation, so Windows-style paths won't work. Your path is relative to the home folder of your app, but I'll look for a reference that discusses this further

Comment: I got what you said. So going by this logic, `file:///` should be referring to root folder of project. So how do I use files from external resources i.e. from local drive?

Comment: Instead of a "local drive," there are 3 types of file locations in Android. I've updated my answer with examples on constructing the URL for each.

Comment: But in any case, my html files and corresponding resources i.e. images, videos, etc. will be placed **within the folder** and hence *.apk size will be approx. equal to size of HTML which can go upto 50Mb also.

Comment: When you deploy content with your app, you'll either have to put it in the apk or download it after the app is installed. I assume you are trying to test your app in the emulator, and don't want the hassle of packaging up a large apk for each debug run?

Comment: hmmmm. So the easier way would be put it into the assets? Also rendering of HTML into the webview is not that simplistic. I need to set initial scale to 50 in order to view the content properly

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10272/discussion-between-tony-the-pony-and-gama)

Answer (score 5):

In Android 4.4 KitKat, a "Not allowed to load local resource: file:///.." is thrown. 
arise when loadURL and the only alternative I've found is "loadDataWithBaseURL".

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/demo/",
                             tmpDocumentText,"text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Comment: `wbHelp.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Help.html");` works in 5.1+
not sure if you need write external storage if it's internal

Answer (score 3):

WebView has loadData method http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

All you need to do is reading the file into String then feed it to WebView using loadData.

Answer (score 0):

either one can use this way to load file specifically if the file is present within android studio project
(pls note android_res is res folder actually and should not be replaced)

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_res/drawable/FILENAME.EXTENSION");
```

but if that is not working please try another way of loading file like

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/demo/",tmpDocumentText,
                         "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```