# Load a local HTML file in the current directory with WebVIew2 (Windows)

Tags: c#, html, windows, webview2

I'm trying to create a barebones WebView2 app that lets me load a specific HTML file from the same directory as wherever the app is located (so if it's on the desktop, installed in the `C:\Windows\` directory, `C:\Users\Poopy\`, wherever.  The HTML file will be titled `main.html` (Or I'll change it to `index.html`)

Still, how can I get whatever the current directory is, and create a file path to load when the app starts?

After some poking around, this is what my Form1.cs has:

```
if (webView != null && webView.CoreWebView2 != null) {
    string currentPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(currentPath + @"\main.html");
    webView.CoreWebView2.NavigateToString(text);
    this.webView.Source = new System.Uri(currentPath + @"\main.html");
}
```

**What I expect to happen**: The blank file, in the same folder as the app, is displayed.  In the case of `main.html`, a white page with the text "hello world" should be displayed.  I will be able to pull up the dev tools popup with F12.

**What actually happens**: If no source is specified in the properties, I get a blank screen with NO web page displaying.  It appears no WebView form shows up; If I press F12 no dev tools pops up.  If a source is specified, and it's a valid entry, I'll load the URL, or if I enter just the filename (assuming it defaults to a relative URL with just `file:///main.html` entered) I get a `ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` error page instead.

Comment: The code `webView.CoreWebView2.NavigateToString(text);` present in the question should work. I'd recommend re-reading [MCVE] guidance on posting code and [edit] the question accordingly. I.e. if you have problem *showing* HTML content - remove all file related code and set `text` to some constant, if you have trouble locating files - adjust code accordingly and explain what you see as results/expect as results.

Comment: Have you tried setting Source to `file:///c:\temp\default.html` (replace with actual path) - notice the 3 `/`

Comment: I'll try that when I get home (got a friend's birthday to go to after work).  I was using `file:\\\ ` instead.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov So I tried that WITHOUT the `this.webView.Source` line and it still doesn't show anything at all - not even an error, acting as if the WebView form didn't exist in the app.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loading html file from local folder into webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223674/loading-html-file-from-local-folder-into-webview)

Comment: @mtk: `WebView` isn't the same as `WebView2`. The documentation for `WebView2` is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/webview2-api-reference

Answer (score 0):

The [SetVirtualHostNameToFolderMapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.setvirtualhostnametofoldermapping?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1056-prerelease) function can help with this. It lets you serve files from a folder to WebView2, and note this bit from the docs:

> Relative paths are interpreted as relative to the folder where the exe of the app is in.

So something like this should do the trick:

```cs
webView.CoreWebView2.SetVirtualHostNameToFolderMapping(hostName: "mycoolapplication",
                                                       folderPath: "",  
                                                       accessKind: CoreWebView2HostResourceAccessKind.Allow);

webView.CoreWebView2.Navigate("https://mycoolapplication/main.html");
```