# Can't open a local PDF in webview using file://

Tags: android, android-webview

I need to display a PDF file located in my app dir in a webwiev without using Google Docs.

This is my code for the webview:

```
public void OpenPDF() {
WebView webview = new WebView(this); 
    setContentView(webview);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
    webview.loadUrl("file://mnt/data/data/com.example.android/files/Docs/test.pdf");;
}
```

I get a blank webview instead of below code works

```
public void OpenPDF() {
WebView webview = new WebView(this); 
    setContentView(webview);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
    webview.loadUrl("file://mnt/data/data/com.example.android/files/Docs/test.html");  
}
```

I tested directly in my web browser with `file://mnt/data/data/com.example.android/files/Docs/test.pdf` and `test.html` and it worked for both. I installed a PDF reader.

```
07-25 17:09:07.967: W/webcore(11347): java.lang.Throwable: EventHub.removeMessages(int what = 107) is not supported before the WebViewCore is set up.
07-25 17:09:07.967: W/webcore(11347):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub.removeMessages(WebViewCore.java:1683)
07-25 17:09:07.967: W/webcore(11347):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub.access$7900(WebViewCore.java:926)
07-25 17:09:07.967: W/webcore(11347):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore.removeMessages(WebViewCore.java:1795)
07-25 17:09:07.967: W/webcore(11347):   at android.webkit.WebView.sendOurVisibleRect(WebView.java:2917)
07-25 17:09:07.967: W/webcore(11347):   at android.webkit.ZoomManager.setZoomScale(ZoomManager.java:593)
07-25 17:09:07.967: W/webcore(11347):   at android.webkit.ZoomManager.access$1700(ZoomManager.java:49)
07-25 17:09:07.967: W/webcore(11347):   at android.webkit.ZoomManager$PostScale.run(ZoomManager.java:984)
07-25 17:09:07.967: W/webcore(11347):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
07-25 17:09:07.967: W/webcore(11347):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-25 17:09:07.967: W/webcore(11347):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-25 17:09:07.967: W/webcore(11347):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-25 17:09:07.967: W/webcore(11347):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-25 17:09:07.967: W/webcore(11347):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-25 17:09:07.967: W/webcore(11347):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-25 17:09:07.967: W/webcore(11347):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-25 17:09:07.967: W/webcore(11347):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any ideas about why only pdf files won't open ?

Answer (score 3):

Their seems to be an answer to your question already in stack overflow at [Open Local Html File in Webview - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812277/open-local-html-file-in-webview-android)

to sum it up : Usage of file:/// before your actual path should solve your problem for everything except .pdf files

Webview does not support PDF in android :(. You need to use google doc according to different sources.

Comment: file:/// works with test.html but without /mnt file:///data/data/com.example.android/files/Docs/test.html"); Still blank for pdf...

Comment: Use 5 / slashes like this  file://///mnt/data/data/com.example.android/files/Docs/test.html

Comment: i added eclipse logs on top when i am trying to open a pdf file

Comment: unfortunatly, Webview does not support PDF in android.

You will need to use google doc.

Comment: damned...can i invoke adobe reader in my app to display my pdf offline ?

Comment: i found my solution here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7437602/how-to-display-a-pdf-via-android-web-browser-without-downloading-first

Comment: What is the proper syntax for using the Google docs approach for a local PDF? None of the above seem to work...

Comment: @Wildchild7 did u find any solution to open a local pdf file in web view

Answer (score -1):

I think you should try with 3 slashes, like that:

```
webview.loadUrl("file:///mnt/data/data/com.example.android/files/Docs/test.pdf");
```

Comment: @AlfieHanssen did u find any solution to open a local pdf file